# How to remove section of a String containing a special character Java

Tags: java, string

I have a string

```
"apples, pears # and bananas\\ngrapes\\nbananas !apples"
```

I want to remove the string substring `# and bananas`.

```
private static String cleaned(String main, String substring) {
    return main.replace(substring, "");
}
```

but `replace` method doesn't work somehow. I feel it has something to do with the  `#` because if I try getting the index of `#` using `main.indexOf("#")` i get `-1`.

When I call the method directly like this

```
System.out.println(cleaned("apples, pears # and bananas\\ngrapes\\nbananas !apples", "# and bananas"));
```

it surprisingly works I get the correct answer
`**apples, pears \ngrapes\nbananas !apples**`. However when I call the method programmatically from another method like this

```
public static String stripComments(String text, String[] commentSymbols) 
    //some code
    return cleaned(stringBuilder.toString(), textAfterComment.toString());
}
```

it does not produce the correct answer. I get `**apples, pears  and bananas\ngrapes\nbananas**`

**Why do I get -1 meaning that `#` is not found yet it is clearly in the string? And how can I remove the substring with or without the replace method ?**

Comment: I tested in my side,and your code works

Comment: Is it possible that the character in the string you receive has another encoding than the one you input with your keyboard? You can check that by encoding the 2 strings here: https://www.browserling.com/tools/utf8-encode 

By the way I already checked for this string you included in the question but I assume your actual string is different.

Comment: There are some [similar Unicode characters for `#`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign). Seeing the following code the beginner's error you probably did not make: `s.replace(u, v); System.out.println(s);` (missing assignment).

Comment: @JoopEggen Please rephrase if you don't mind i have still not understood.

Comment: `replace` doesn't modify the (immutable) input string, but rather returns the updated string.

Comment: Sorry my fault. That `indexOf(`#")` would give -1  is baffling, a second error I thought. You might try `indexOf('#')` - a char. That would prevent some invisible char being copied. I was thinking maybe some Unicode twin was copied. There are very similar characters see Wikipedia link. Furthermore you could have forgotten to assign the result of the replace call.

Comment: I think Joop is suggesting that your input string might *look like* it contains `# and bananas`, but in fact it contains a different character which *resembles* `#`.  It might be `＃ and bananas` or `﹟ and bananas` or `♯ and bananas`.